# Building Angular dynamic form in nested

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am making an angular 6 application using **Angular dynamic form**, using the link https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Where I am in the need to display the form in nested format...

**Scenario 1**:

// Filling Project name and description

Initially, there will be two text boxes called project name and description,

```
let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [
  new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'project_name',
    label: 'Project name',
    required: true,
    type: 'text',
    order: 1
  }),

  new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'description',
    label: 'Description',
    type: 'text',
    order: 2
  })
];
```

after filling up two fields user will click on add at the bottom of this form.

**Scenario 2**:

// Getting another form on click add

After clicking the add, another form with the inputs as,

```
let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [
  new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'property_one',
    label: 'Property One',
    required: true,
    type: 'text',
    order: 1
  }),

  new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'property_two',
    label: 'Property Two',
    type: 'text',
    order: 2
  }),

  new DropdownQuestion({
    key: 'level',
    label: 'Priority Level',
    options: [
      { key: 'low', value: 'Low' },
      { key: 'medium', value: 'Medium' },
      { key: 'high', value: 'High' },
    ],
    order: 3
  }),
];
```

Needs to be displayed.

After filling up both the two forms and click on save the entire data needs to get stored.

My working example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysy2xa

Where I am making two forms but it is taking up the last generated form. I know it a wrong approach, as I am very new in angular dynamic form, kindly help me to achieve the result of generating a new form (With properties) on clicking the add after filing up the first two input fields (Project name and description)...

Comment: your stack blitz is not working

Comment: Its working only https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysy2xa

Comment: am getting error if i click add or remove.

Comment: @Chellappan, That is dummy function i need to get another form using that click thats what i need solution.. Kindly help me please.. I am stucked in this for a long time..

Comment: you want to access child form value in parent right?

Comment: @Chellappan, Yes you are right..

Comment: if it is possible please add working stackblitz

Comment: @Chellappan, I am new in angular hence help me out..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182927/discussion-between-chellappan-and-mani-raj).

Comment: It's the same questin that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100173/angular-dynamic-form-nested-fields/53100753#53100753

Comment: @Eliseo, Here i am in the need of another form but there i need to have nested fields.. I am in the need of good help from your side to get the result there its enough to tackle this question with that.. Just need a working stackblitz from you in that answer please..