# FormArray - How to pass a string array to it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-material

This is my FormGroup:

```
this.productGroup = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80)])],
  variants: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      type: '',
      options: this.fb.array([])
    })
  ])
});
```

How to pass a string array to `options`? Like this `[ 'string1', 'string2' ]`. I'm dinamically getting those values here: [stackblitz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109833/angular-material-matchiplist-how-to-use-it-on-a-dynamic-formarray/53110689#comment93143214_53110689), however i'm not sure how to fill the array. I would like to pass a generic string array directly to `options`.

`variants` array example:

```
variants: [ 
   { type: 'Color', options: ['Red', 'Blue'] },
   { type: 'Size', options: ['Small', 'Medium', 'Big'] }
]
```

Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="productGroup">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <div formArrayName="variants" *ngFor="let item of productGroup.controls['variants'].controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Variable Type" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="type" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type">
            {{type}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-chip-list #chipList>
          <mat-chip *ngFor="let opt of typesOptionsArray[i]" [selectable]="true"
                    [removable]="true" (removed)="removeOpt(opt, i)">
            {{opt}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
          </mat-chip>
          <input placeholder="Type Options"
                  [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                  [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                  [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true"
                  (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addOpt($event, i)">
        </mat-chip-list>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="javascript:" (click)="addItem()"> Add Variant </a>
      <a href="javascript:" (click)="removeItem(i)" *ngIf="i > 0"> Remove Variant </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: options values are checkbox in the UI?

Comment: No, it's `Angular Material MatChips`. I get a new value everytime a user add a new chip (event), then add it to a string array in my component.

Comment: @AjayOjha I'm trying `this.typesOptionsArray[index].forEach(type => {
        this.productGroup.controls['variants']['options'].push(new FormControl(type));
      });` to pass the string array to FormArray directly

Comment: can you please share your variants html code ?

Comment: @AjayOjha there you go. It's kind of complex because of its dynamic generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a sample application on [stackblitz for adding array value in the options array](https://stackblitz.com/edit/string-array-value-in-form-control?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

I would suggest instead of creating FormArray of options field try to create FormControl. I have changed the code of creating FormGroup.

Here is the code of formgroup.

```js
 this.productGroup = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80)])],
  variants: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      type: '',
      options: ''
    })
  ])
});
```

I have added two methods in the component 'addOption' and 'removeOption' while adding option at that time you need to push a string into the options array.

Here is the code :

```js
let variants = <FormArray>this.productGroup.controls.variants;
let variantFormGroup = <FormGroup>variants.controls[0];
let optionValue = variantFormGroup.controls.options.value;
if(!optionValue)
    optionValue = [];
optionValue.push(`chip${this.currentIndex}`); // push your actutal string value
variantFormGroup.controls.options.setValue(optionValue);

this.currentIndex++; //don't consider this, this is just for adding new name
```

Here is the code of remove string value from the options array

```js
 let optionValue = this.productGroup.value.variants[0].options;
    if(optionValue.length > 0){
      //let indexOf = optionValue.indexOf(removeValue); find the index number with your value.
      optionValue.splice(0,1);
      let variants = <FormArray>this.productGroup.controls.variants;
      let variantFormGroup = <FormGroup>variants.controls[0];
      variantFormGroup.controls.options.setValue(optionValue);

    }
```

here is the json result after adding few values in the options array:

```js
{ "name": "", "variants": [ { "type": "", "options": [ "chip4", "chip5", "chip6", "chip7", "chip8" ] } ] }
```

please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thank you! I've used a similar approach to save an array of images, but I wasn't sure if it would be possible to apply it dinamically.

Comment: Is it possible to store `options` in a array of objects instead of array: `this.productGroup = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80)])],
  variants: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      type: '',
      options: this.fb.array([ this.fb.group({ option: '', photos: ''  ])
    })
  ])
});`

Comment: Yes it is possible, do you need me to design?

Comment: Yes... I'm doing something wrong it's always returning an array

Comment: Provide the stackbliz link I will do the change and let you know

Comment: here: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/string-array-value-in-form-control-kqro1c) ... It's your Stackblitz with the desired change... chips needs to be inside option

Comment: now chips are adding inside the option; check on this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/string-array-value-in-form-control-s7yua8?file=src/app/app.component.ts ; what about remove?

Comment: Almost there... I'm trying to use a new object instead of a new element of the array `"variants": [ { "options": [ { "option": "chip0", "photos": "" }, {"option": "chip1", photos: '' }... ] ]`

Comment: check now https://stackblitz.com/edit/string-array-value-in-form-control-s7yua8?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: for using option values like an array in the template it must be something like this: `let opt of this.productGroup.value.variants[i].options.value`?

Comment: Yes, in *ngFor loop, put *ngIf before this otherwise it will give error.

Comment: I can't do this because its a mat-form-field... i need to initialize it somehow

Comment: you can put '?' to handle null object.

Comment: I'm using `<div formArrayName="variants" *ngFor="let item of productGroup.controls['variants'].controls; let i = index;">
          <div [formGroupName]="i"> <input formControlName="name"> //options needs to be here </div> </div>` for my dynamic fields. Should I keep this structure for options?

Comment: do you want to show options array value in the htmlcontrol or show as text?

Comment: mat-chip needs an array `<mat-chip *ngFor="let opt of item">`. But i'm generating objects instead of just an array, maybe it's better to keep an variable to handle it. However I can't populate this array when I receive the whole `product` from database. Could you help me to populate this 'control array´ that will be used in the mat-chip?

Comment: item should be `[ [ 'chip0', 'chip1'], ['chip2' ... ] ]`

Comment: can you please write your html in the stackblitz example and share it with me. I will do the correction as expected.

Comment: there you go: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzed82) ... I need to prepopulate the FormGroup (mat-chips too) and fix this `typesOptionsArray´ to work properly (sometimes it removes the wrong index)

Comment: sorry forgot about the upload service... now its uploading too

Comment: what is the use of upload service?

Comment: im passing the images from user file input to `url[][]` and `files[][]` arrays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183650/discussion-between-ajay-ojha-and-james).