# Patch the values in angular form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am making an application using angular 6, where i am using angular dynamic  form.

As of creating the form and submitting i have completed everything, You could able to see the working **stackblitz**, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-hne6fg

FYI: This form has children elemts which will gets opened and also gets append on click the add button and removes one by last on click the remove button..

The thing i am in the need is, i just need to patch the values to each inputs via service during edit of each row respectively..

Say i call the **get service** as,

```
    this.dynamicFormService.getRest(url,token).subscribe(res => {
        this.form.value = res.data;   //Tried this line but got error (Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a constant or a read-only property)
     })
```

I am trying to patch the values to the form which you can see in **dynamic-form.ts** in stacblitz,

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
}
```

If i console the the form as `console.log(this.form.value)`, it gives the result as,

```
template_desc: ""
template_name: ""
template_properties: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And `console.log(res.data)` in get service result gives,

```
data:
template_obj_id: "123"
template_desc: "New template description"
template_name: "New Template"
template_properties: Array(1)
0:
property_name: "Property name"
property_origin: ["VBM"]
property_required: true
property_type: "Property type"
```

I just need to bind this data that comes from **res.data** to get patched to all the form inputs.

These are the values i need to patch to all the inputs respectively like `template_name` has the **value** as New Template and `template_desc` as `New template description` etc..

And also an another important thing for `template_properties` value which is array will get open on click add button during create but whereas during edit it should get opened automatically with number of rows present inside `template_properties`..

Though the question went little bigger for explanation, the thing i am in the need is single.. I need to patch the data comes from service **(res.data)** to each form elements respectively and all the form elements including `template_properties` needs to be visible in which user can edit and submit the form.

The screenshot of res.data, [image]

Tried with the below answer,

```
 this.form.patchValue({
      template_desc: res.data.template_desc,
      template_name:  res.data.template_name,
    });
```

But if i give `template_properties: res.data.template_properties`, the template properties not getting binded but other two `template name and desc` getting binded..

Kindly help to achieve the patching of data to the form elements...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-xcychx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form.component.html, I put as "path the values".

The only thing to take account is that you need add to the form as element as has the array.

```
  //This function serve to add to the array the elments of the arrays
  //Is the same that we use when add a new line to the Array Form
  addControls(control: string) {
    let question: any = this.questions.find(q => q.key == control);
    let children = question ? question.children : null;
    if (children)
      (this.form.get(control) as FormArray).push(this.qcs.toFormGroup(children))
  }
  this.dynamicFormService.getRest(url,token).subscribe(res => {
        //In res.data you have the data.
        //In res.dat.template_properties you has the array

        //Create the Form
        this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
        //Add so element at array as was necesary
        for (let i=0;i<this.data.myArray.length;i++)
        {
            this.addControls('template_properties')
        }
        //Finally use patchValue
        this.form.patchValue(res.data);
    }
```

Well, your data not corresponding with this.questions and there are a problem with your property_origin (about the problem with as convert propertyOrigin to a series of checkBox, let me some time -I'll updated this anwser more later-)

**Updated**
see [stackblitz updated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-a8fkn7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion-control.service.ts)
Creating a new Question Type to create a list of checkBox
There're a problem with the checkBox. In Angular a checkBox can be have only two values "true" or "false". Until I know, there no effect the attrib value.

So, we can not make something like

```
<input type="checkbox" value="car" formControlName="checkName">
<input type="checkbox" value="dog" formControlName="checkName">
```

To get in "checkName" an array ['car','dog'] if you checked the two values.

How we can solutionated this? I think that the better idea is has a formGroup like

```
<div formGroupName="checkName">
  <input type="checkBox" formControlName="car">
  <input type="checkBox" formControlName="dog">
</div>
```

So, we'll get some like

```
   checkName={car:true,dog:false}
```

Well one work is make a new QuestionType "ListCheckBoxQuestion"

```
export class ListCheckBoxQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'list-chekbox';
  options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options['options'] || [];
  }
}
```

After we can change the dinamic-formquestion.component adding a new switch. See that we create a formGroupName with the question.key, and inside this group we create a formControlName using "options"

```
<div [formGroupName]="question.key"  *ngSwitchCase="'list-chekbox'" >
  <ng-container *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
  <input type="checkbox"  [formControlName]="opt.key">
                <label >{{opt.value}}</label>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Well, the hard part is wen we create the form (the toFormGroup function of question-control-service

```
toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[]) {
    let group: any = {};

    questions.forEach(question => {
      if (question.controlType=="array") {
         group[question.key]=new FormArray([]);
      }else if (question.controlType=="list-chekbox")
      { //We create a FromGroup using the options
        let controls:any={};
        for (let option of question.options)
             controls[option.key]=new FormControl(false);
        group[question.key]=new FormGroup(controls);
        console.log("*",question);
      }
      else {
       ...
      }
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

Well there're a job to to that is convert our form.value to data and the data received to form.value.

When we received some like ["car","dog"] we must transform to {car:true,dog:true} and when we have {car:true,dog:false} we must transform to ["car"]. We must use map

**Update**
Take a look to the function toFormGroup of question-control-service. This function is the function that create the form. In the last version we add so many lines to the array as values length. Change this funcion to add a linea if no value is indicated

```
questions.forEach(question => {
      if (question.controlType == "array") {
        group[question.key] = new FormArray([]);
        if (question.value) {
          if (question.children) {
            //If question.children we must to give "value" to the children
            //So the children has as value, the value given in dataArray
            for (let value of question.value) {
              Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
                let qu = question.children.find(x => x.key == key)
                if (qu) {
                  qu.value = value[key];
                  qu.controlType = qu.elementType
                }
              })
              group[question.key].push(this.toFormGroup(question.children))
            }
          }
        } //Add this lines to add one line to the array if no 
          //value is indicated
    else {
      if (question.children) {
        question.children.forEach(qu => {
          qu.controlType = qu.elementType

        })
        group[question.key].push(this.toFormGroup(question.children))
      }
    }
```

Comment: @ManiRaj, I update the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-a8fkn7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form.component.ts. There're several changes, so I add a README.txt explain the code. I supouse that you have different "json", one for model and onw for data, but I'm not sure that really you have an unique json with the data and model joinned. In that case the code must be changed

Comment: Finally I think I got it. In https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-yq4smf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion-control.service.ts you has a dinamic-form feed by an unique jsonData that mix data and model

Comment: @Mai I update the answer. The key is understand the function foFormGroup. There're a "strange step" that is give a new property to the childrens: "controlType", necesary to show the controls

Comment: Eliseo, I have made changes with you code but i couldn't able to get the form itself  .. The stacblitz with your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-z49wgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion-control.service.ts

Comment: If i am wrong please update the stackblitz too with opening of one children array at initial stage..

Comment: I'am explaining bad. You must add the lines I indicate but NOT delete all the rest of the function, see my https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-28ysqg?file=src/app/question-control.service.ts

Comment: Eliseo, How can i call a service with data to the JSON?? For dropdown the key and value is coming from a service but here we hard coded it inside options.. Any suggestion to use the data from service to the JSON (dropdown options)..

Comment: Hi Eliseo, From this solution first few function was very clear about the patch data from service for the whole form.. Likewise how can i patch only ```template_properties``` from a service?? If you give this information then it would be helpful for me to patch the children values alone as i am doing cloning like scenario here.. In dropdown selecting a value and the data regarding it coming from service.. That should get patched to children alone..

Answer (score 0):

Use `patchValue` to set the data to form

```
this.dynamicFormService.getRest(url,token).subscribe(res => {
   this.form.patchValue({
      template_desc: res.data.template_desc,
      template_name:  res.data.template_name,
    });
 }
```

Comment: And also what will happen to ```template_properties``` as it gets opened on click add button but during this patching, it needs to get opened automatically and the respective data of ```template_properties``` needs to get filled..