# Remove the selected option from select box

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, select, angular-reactive-forms

I am making angular application with angular form.

Here i have given a form with input fields `first name and last name` which will always showing..

After that i am having children which will be displayed upon clicking the add button and the children will get removed on click remove button.

As of now everything works fine.

Here i am making patching of data to the inputs on click option from select box.. The neccessary inputs gets patched..

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">

        <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
            <ng-container *ngIf="question.children">
                <div [formArrayName]="question.key">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of form.get(question.key).controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                        <div *ngFor="let item of question.children">
                            <app-question [question]="item" [form]="form.get(question.key).at(i)"></app-question>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              <select multiple (change)="changeEvent($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of persons" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="!question.children">
                <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
            </ng-container>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <!-- <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button> -->
    </div>
  </form> <br>

  <!-- Need to have add and remove button.. <br><br> -->

  <button (click)="addControls('myArray')"> Add </button>
  <button (click)="removeControls('myArray')"> Remove </button><br/><br/>
  <pre>
{{form?.value|json}}
</pre>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
 changeEvent(e) {
    if (e.target.value == 1) {
      let personOneChild = [
        { property_name : "Property one" },
        { property_name : "Property two" },
      ]
      for (let i = 0; i < personOneChild.length; i++) {
        this.addControls('myArray')
      }
      this.form.patchValue({
          'myArray': personOneChild
        });
    } 
    if (e.target.value == 2) {
      let personTwoChild = [
        { property_name : "Property three" },
        { property_name : "Property four" },
        { property_name : "Property five" },
      ]
      for (let i = 0; i < personTwoChild.length; i++) {
        this.addControls('myArray')
      }
      this.form.patchValue({
          'myArray': personTwoChild
        });
    }
  }

  addControls(control: string) {
    let question: any = this.questions.find(q => q.key == control);
    let children = question ? question.children : null;
    if (children)
      (this.form.get(control) as FormArray).push(this.qcs.toFormGroup(children))
  }

  removeControls(control: string) {
    let array = this.form.get(control) as FormArray;
    array.removeAt(array.length - 1);
  }
```

Clear **working stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-fnclvf

You can work around in the above link that if you select the person one option then the value named `property one and property two` gets binded to the inputs and in select box the `property one` is highlighted as selected..

The thing i am in need is **actually from here**,
I am having a remove button, you can see in demo.. If i click the remove button, one at last will be got removed and again click the last gets removed..
Here i am having two property `one and two`, if i remove both the inputs with remove button, the the **highlighted** value `person one` in select box needs **to** get **not highlighted**.

This is actually my requirement.. If i remove either one property then it should be still in highlighted state.. Whereas **completely removing** the both properties it should not be highlighted..

Hope you got my point of explanation.. If any needed i am ready to provide.

**Note:** I use **ng-select** for it as i am unable implement that library, i am making it with html 5 select box.. In [ng-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select) library it will be like adding and removing the option.. Any solution with ng-select library also appreciable..

Kindly help me to achieve the result please..

Real time i am having in application like this:

**Selected three templates and each has one property with one,two,three respectively:**

If choose a dropdown then the property values for the respective will get added as children.

[image]

**Here you can see i have deleted the property name three for which the parent is template three and the template three still shows in select box even though i removed its children**

[image]

Comment: what is the use case can you explain

Comment: @Chellappan, I have updated my question.. In demo you an see the if i select person one then ```person one``` will get highlighted as selected and the children named ```property one and property two``` gets patched to form respectively.. I also have remove button which removes the one at last if i remove the children of the parent then parent should also get deselected.. In my application it should need to get removed from that dropdown.. Updated my question with image hope you get clear..

Comment: @Chellappan, In the application why i am using this scenario is while creating a new template, it has some properties related to previous created templates so in order to again enter those values user allowed to clone the data of properties from already created templates..So from dropdown if i select a template then the property related to it will get patched and adding the next template then it goes on one by one..Suppose if i wish to remove any property then that corresponding parent needs to get removed from select box..It still showing there even though i have removed the children property

Comment: @Chellappan, Not last one but its children.. Here you can see the person one has two children so after removing those two the selected item needs to get deselected.. In ng-select library if we use multiple select the it will get added one by one as shown in image so i need to remove it from that dropdown if its children removed..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get a reference to the select, like so:

HTML:

```
<select multiple (change)="changeEvent($event)" #mySelect>
  <option *ngFor="let opt of persons" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// ...

@ViewChild('mySelect') select;
```

Then, in your remove function, check if all elements have been removed, and if they have, set the `value` of the `select` to `null`

```
if (array.length === 0) {
  this.select.nativeElement.value = null;
}
```

**[Here is a fork of the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-n358yg?file=src/app/dynamic-form.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks..How to clear a single option alone if we delete those children..Say i we select option ```person one and two``` and delete the person two' children but not one so option two alone needs to get deselected..

Comment: Or else if thats not possible then kindly help me to not allow add and remove below for the children.. But can add and remove extra textboxes after listing down.. But that should not be related to the parent and children.. So that there cannot be any deselection if we not allow to remove option for children..