# Angular dynamic form with groups of elements getting from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am making angular application and building of angular dynamic form.

Here i am trying to split of form in two parts such as Person Name and Personal details..

For Person Name its working for grouping but for Personal details its not working.

The **Html**:

```
<div *ngIf="form">
  <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row" [formGroup]="form">
      <ng-container *ngIf="!question.children">
        <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="question.controlType === 'group' && question.children && question.children.length > 0">
        <app-dynamic-group [questions]="question.children" [form]="form.controls[question.key]" [key]="question.key" [formControlName]="question.key"></app-dynamic-group>
      </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JSON**:

```
  jsonData: any = [
    {
      "elementType": "group",
      "key": "person_name",
      "children": [
        {
          "elementType": "textbox",
          "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
          "key": "first_name",
          "label": "First Name",
          "type": "text",
          "value": "",
          "required": true,
          "minlength": 3,
          "maxlength": 20,
          "order": 1
        },
        {
          "elementType": "textbox",
          "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
          "key": "last_name",
          "label": "Last Name",
          "type": "text",
          "value": "",
          "required": true,
          "order": 2
        }
     ],
    },
        {
      "elementType": "group",
      "key": "personal_details",
      "children": [
        {
          "elementType": "textbox",
          "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
          "key": "email",
          "label": "Email",
          "type": "text",
          "value": "",
          "required": true,
          "minlength": 3,
          "maxlength": 20,
          "order": 1
        },
        {
          "elementType": "textbox",
          "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
          "key": "mobile",
          "label": "Mobile",
          "type": "text",
          "value": "",
          "required": true,
          "order": 2
        }
     ],
    },
  ];
```

**The working Stckblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-5uj52y

As of working everything works fine.. Already a group was made for Person name and its working fine but for Personal details i am unable to find the input boxes..

A single form needs to get split up with titles above each part thats the requirement of this form.

Here the `{{question.key}}` displays the name on each input boxes but i need to display only `Person Name` at top.. Because it is the parent title and the remaining such as `First Name`, `Last Name` are input box labels.. How to show the parent title alone in before of each part (**Person Name (Has First and Last Name) , Personal Details (Has Email and Mobile)**)...

I would like to have order split up exactly like the below with title for each respectively.

**Person Name**

```
 -> First Name
 -> Last Name
```

**Personal Details**

```
 -> Email
 -> Mobile Number
```

If i am wrong with the above approach then kindly help me to split this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-geesde dynamic form like the below given approach..

My form needs to look like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zc34qr but it needs to be in pure angular dynamic form and JSON loading..

Kindly help me to create a group `Personal Details` like the `Person Name` which was already created and working..

Stuck for a long duration in this kindly help me please...

Comment: The 'Person Name' text is not available in the JSON, then how can show that it will be good if you add one more field on group level like 'groupTitle:"Person Name"' and that is very easy to show on the UI. In your dynamic form, only validations or some other validations are also coming in near future?

Comment: @AjayOjha, I had given ```key``` in each group .. You can see in service.ts  ``` "elementType": "group",
      "key": "person_name",```

Comment: @AjayOjha, No any validations may come in future..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you creates additional formGroup here:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({main: innerForm});
```

Just use formGroup you're getting from your service:

**dynamic-form.component.ts**

```
this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
```

**dynamic-form.component.html**

```
<app-dynamic-group [questions]="questions" [form]="form"></app-dynamic-group>
```

Now, you do not need to implement ControlValueAccessor on your DynamicGroupComponent. You're passing FormGroup to it and it should be enough to generate form dynamically.

**dynamic-group.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-group',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-group.component.html'
})
export class DynamicGroupComponent {
  @Input() form: FormGroup;

  @Input() questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];
}
```

**dynamic-group.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
    <app-question *ngIf="!question.children" [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>

    <app-dynamic-group 
       *ngIf="question.controlType === 'group' && question.children && question.children.length"
       [form]="form.get(question.key)"
       [questions]="question.children">
    </app-dynamic-group>
</div>
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-spjp7e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. I would like to place the respective title above each part.. You have split the form into two how to place the title on each above.. Say ```Person Name``` for first box and ```Personal Details``` for second box as title i need to show.. Also mentioned this one in question..

Comment: Updated example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-spjp7e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion.service.ts