# How to generate a HTML FORM from JSON in Angular 7

Tags: html, json, angular, forms, angular7

**I want to generate a HTML FORM from below JSON.**

```
{  
   "templateName":"C-Learn Survey",
   "surveyQuestions":[  
      {  
         "questionTitle":"Enter your name",
         "questionType":"Text",
         "questionGroup":{  

         }
      },
      {  
         "questionTitle":"Enter your empid:",
         "questionType":"Text",
         "questionGroup":{  

         }
      },
      {  
         "questionTitle":"Select your technologies",
         "questionType":"Multi choice",
         "questionGroup":{  
            "options":[  
               {  
                  "optionText":"Java"
               },
               {  
                  "optionText":"Mule"
               },
               {  
                  "optionText":".net"
               }
            ],
            "showRemarksBox":false
         }
      },
      {  
         "questionTitle":"Gender",
         "questionType":"Single choice",
         "questionGroup":{  
            "options":[  
               {  
                  "optionText":"Male"
               },
               {  
                  "optionText":"Female"
               }
            ],
            "showRemarksBox":false
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

*for example*

```
{  
             "questionTitle":"Enter your name",
             "questionType":"Text",
             "questionGroup":{  

             }
```

*for the above json there should be a html form element like this*

```
<label>Enter your name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
```

I am new to Angular and seen some post and code on internet saying that It is possible through jquery Please suggest me how to achieve that. I am using Angular 7.

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53357556/7785337 might help you in building angular form using the JSON..

Comment: See google documentation https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Answer (score 8):

Try this [Angular6-json-schema-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular6-json-schema-form)

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-json-schema-form-example)

In your typescript file

```
import { jsonSchema } from './jsonSchema';

jsonFormOptions = {
    loadExternalAssets: false,
  };
  schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "first_name": { "type": "string" },
      "last_name": { "type": "string" },
      "address": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "street_1": { "type": "string" },
          "street_2": { "type": "string" },
          "city": { "type": "string" },
          "state": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [ "AL", "AK", "AS", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE",
                "DC", "FM", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA",
                "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MH", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS",
                "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND",
                "MP", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PW", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD",
                "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VI", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" ]
          },
          "zip_code": { "type": "string" }
        }
      },
      "birthday": { "type": "string" },
      "notes": { "type": "string" },
      "phone_numbers": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": { "type": "string", "enum": [ "cell", "home", "work" ] },
            "number": { "type": "string" }
          },
          "required": [ "type", "number" ]
        }
      }
    },
    "required": [ "last_name" ]
  };
```

In your html file

```
<json-schema-form
  [schema]="schema"
  [layout]="layout"
  [options]='jsonFormOptions'
  [framework]="'bootstrap-4'"
  (onSubmit)="onSubmit($event)"
  (formSchema)="showFormSchemaFn($event)"
  (formLayout)="showFormLayoutFn($event)">
</json-schema-form>
```

Comment: Can I use this for angular 10 as well?